# Draw a metrics on image with number of column and row

Tags: android, image, imageview

I want to draw a metrics with some number of columns and rows over an image which will have cell nos as 1,2,3 ... and so on.

I am trying this but didn't found any solution can anyone help to get rid of this.
I want this to work as a Grid View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution Using this..

```
for (float row = (r.top/size1); row < PosterActivity.mNoOfRows+(r.top/size1); row++) {
                        float y = (row * size1);
                        for (float col = (r.left/size); col < PosterActivity.mNoOfColumns+(r.left/size); col++) {
                            float x = (col * size);
                            //                      canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + size, y + size1, paint1);

                            if ((int)col == myX && (int)row == myY) {
                                canvas.drawRect(x,y, x + size,y + size1, paint);
//                              Log.i("Draw X"+x,"Draw Y"+y);
                                Log.i("Touch Event Occured:","==>"+num);
                                //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + num,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                            num++;
                        }
//                  }
```